# how can i make image editor in react native?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, image-editing

i'm making a image editor application using react native.

just adding function of and a shape like circle or square.

```
_handleAddCircle() {
    let circle = {
        left: 20,
        top: 84
    };
    let circles = this.state.circles;
    circles.push(circle);
    this.setState({
        circles: circles
    });
},

render: function() {
    let circles = this.state.circles.map((circle, key) => {
        return (
            <Circle key={key} left={circle.left} top={circle.top} updatePosition={this.updatePosition} />
        );
    });
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableHighlight
                style={styles.button}
                onPress={this._handleAddCircle}
                underlayColor="#88D4F5">
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>add</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
            <ScrollView ref="resultImage" style={styles.scrollView}>
                <Image
                    style={styles.image}
                    source={require('../../resources/images/1422374259704.jpeg')} />
                {circles}
            </ScrollView>
            <TouchableHighlight
                style={styles.button}
                onPress={this._handleSave}
                underlayColor="#88D4F5">
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>save</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
}
```

but i cannot find saving image after working.

i guess hard to make image editor without native language.

what package or plugin do i need for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a package like https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot that would allow you to wrap your image + overlays :

`<ViewShot ref="viewShot" options={{ format: "png", quality: 1 }}>
  <ScrollView ref="resultImage" style={styles.scrollView}>
    <Image
      style={styles.image}
      source={require('../../resources/images/1422374259704.jpeg')} />
    {circles}
  </ScrollView>
</ViewShot>`

and then capture it :

`this.refs.viewShot.capture()`

Comment: Will it give us same image quality? or will the image quality gets compromised?

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use https://github.com/eneskarpuz/react-native-drag-text-editor for all text editing actions in your image editor app.

```js
 ...
import DragTextEditor from 'react-native-drag-text-editor';
...   
   <DragTextEditor
          minWidth={100}
          minHeight={100}
          w={200}
          h={200}
          x={WINDOW.width/4}
          y={WINDOW.height/3}
          FontColor={"#000000"}
          LineHeight={15}
          TextAlign={"left"}
          LetterSpacing={0}
          FontSize={15}
          isDraggable={true}
          isResizable={true}
          /> 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go through this awesome library: [gl-react-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gl-react-native), using which you can create your own filters, image cropper and a lots more